# Does this effect around the sun have a name ? How do i get that effect?

Tags: sun

What is this effect called? Where there are lines of light rays emanating from the center ? How do i get that effect?  Does it need some kind of special lens or filter to get ? Or does it require post processing to achieve that effect ?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd be suspicious that the third example hasn't been added in post...

Comment: @PhilipKendall the sun position is consistent with the shadows and the faces have no direct sun, so I'd say it's genuine.

Comment: @MarkRansom oh absolutely, the sun itself isn't added in post, but the flares are just a bit too perfect. I could be wrong, and it doesn't really matter.

Comment: That other linked question was indeed very helpful. Should i delete this question now ? What is the policy/etiquette in this situation ?

Comment: Don't worry about deleting the question.  As long as it doesn't have any votes I think the "roomba" bot will clean it up.  A mod or consensus of power users could delete it too if it looked like it was bad for the site, but I don't think it is.